# How to notify the page when GoBack() happened?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Here is what my app does:

The first page can navigate to the second page, and the second page displays a list of data. The user can choose one of them then the app will bring the data back to the first page.

Sounds easy, but I'm confused with the Windows Mobile Navigation Model.

The first page navigates to the second page, using this code:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

and the second page uses the code below to go back:

```
this.Frame.GoBack();
```

How could the first page know if the second page disappeared? I want to update the UI on the first page after the second page disappeared.
Now, I used a static class to keep the data that user picks, but I have no idea when should be the right time to update the first page.

Is there any way to get an event or notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple, since UWP does this for you. I noticed you're not using MVVM, so you can simply override the `OnNavigatedTo` event in your page. This event is triggered when navigation to your page is completed (and thus the second screen dissapeared). Simply check for `NavigationMode.Back` to confirm you're returning and not navigating forward.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        // coming from 2nd page, so refresh your data
    }
}
```